# Texture gets distorted while rendering

Tags: rendering

Before rendering, my project looks like this:

[image: Before rendering]

When I render it, the visuals get distorted. What can I do?

[image: After rendering]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like there's a duplicate cylinder object on top of your barrel. Look in your outliner (the UI element that shows a list of all the things in your scene.)

Are there objects there that are hidden? It is possible for an object to be hidden from the viewport mode, but still appear in the render.